# Pascal's Triangle Problem?

Tags: number-theory, functions, logic

Guys I have been trying to solve this problem for a long time but cant seem to come up with anything. Problem is essentially a Pascal triangle but I cant figure out how to sum up a column for a specific time, t. Please help. Following is the problem:

Consider a bacterial cell constrained to a one-dimensional environment (some sort of tube, for example). This bacteria reproduce by binary fission: Every hour, each cell divides into two equal daughter cells. Immediately after the division, two daughter cells move away from each other and stop at points x + 1 and x − 1, where x is the original position of their parent cell before the fission. 
The process starts with a single cell located at x = 0. We set the clock to t = 0 in the beginning of the experiment. After one hour, at time t = 1, there are two cells: at x = −1 and at x = 1, respectively. The process continues indefinitely. 
Let N(t,x) be the number of cells at the position x at the time t. Derive a formula for N(t,x).

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s clear that $N(t,x)=N(t,-x)$ for all $t\ge 0$ and all $x$. The recurrence is straightforward:

$$N(t+1,x)=N(t,x-1)+N(t,x+1)\;,$$

with initial value $N(0,0)=1$ and $N(0,x)=0$ for $x\ne 0$. The first few values:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
t\backslash x&-4&-3&-2&-1&0&+1&+2&+3&+4\\ \hline
0&&&&&1\\
1&&&&1&0&1\\
2&&&1&0&2&0&1\\
3&&1&0&3&0&3&0&1\\
4&1&0&4&0&6&0&4&0&1
\end{array}$$

Empirically it’s clear that this is just Pascal’s triangle with zeroes inserted between the entries and the horizontal indexing shifted. Fix $t\ge 0$: as $x$ runs from $-t$ to $t$ in steps of $2$, we get the binomial coefficients $\binom{t}k$ for $k=0,\ldots,t$. In other words, we can see that

$$N(t,-t+2k)=\binom{t}k$$

for $k=0,\ldots,t$ and that $N(t,x)=0$ for all other values of $x$. This can be rephrased a bit more nicely: since you get $k$ from $-t+2k$ by adding $t$ and dividing by $2$, we can see that

$$N(t,x)=\begin{cases}
\binom{t}{\frac{x+t}2},&\text{if }x+t\text{ is even}\\\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

To finish the problem, you need only prove by induction on $t$ that this is actually correct.

Comment: Many thanks for the clear explanation but the function N(t,x) asks for the number of bacteria at position x at time t. As I understand, this means function should produce a sum of all the bacteria residing at x for the time t and t before that time. For example N(4,2) should produce 5(4 bacteria cells at t=4 + 0 bacteria cells at t=3 + 1 bacteria cell at t= 2 + 0 at t= 1 + 0 at t= 0). It was this adding up a column of Pascal triangle I was originally struggling with. Please help.

Comment: @GdgamesGamers: Ah, I see: you’re assuming that they persist indefinitely. That’s fairly ugly; I suspect that there is no nice closed form.

Comment: Actually it turns out that the answer you provided was exactly what my professor was looking for. He explained that after a bacteria cell divides, it no longer counts as a cell thus no need to add up any column of values. Many thanks for your help !

Comment: @GdgamesGamers: You’re welcome!